# Typescript use generic type indexing array properities in function error

Tags: typescript, generics

```js
interface AllEvents {
    showDialog: (dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void
    loading: (isLoading: true | false) => void
}

type Events = {
    [key in keyof AllEvents]: AllEvents[key][];
};
const commonEvents:Events  = {
    showDialog: [],
    loading   : [],
};

function subscribe<K extends keyof AllEvents>(eventName: K, callback: AllEvents[K]) {
    let a =commonEvents[eventName]
    a.push(callback);  //error
}
```

the error comes form   `a.push(callback);`

TS2345: Argument of type 'AllEvents[K]' is not assignable to parameter of type '((dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void) & ((isLoading: boolean) => void)'.

```
 Type '((dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void) | ((isLoading: boolean) => void)' is not assignable to type '((dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void) & ((isLoading: boolean) => void)'.

 Type '(dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void' is not assignable to type '((dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void) & ((isLoading: boolean) => void)'.

 Type '(dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void' is not assignable to type '(isLoading: boolean) => void'.

 Type 'AllEvents[K]' is not assignable to type '(dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void'.

 Type '((dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void) | ((isLoading: boolean) => void)' is not assignable to type '(dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void'.

 Type '(isLoading: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type '(dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void'.

 Types of parameters 'isLoading' and 'dialogName' are incompatible.

 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

`commonEvents[eventName]` can be `showDialog` and its type should be   `((dialogName: string, props: Record<string, any>) => void)[]` what is wrong with this?

Comment: If I translate the answer from the duplicated question here, it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/lm0Jqw).